# Touchend event сколько длится?

Tags: jquery, mobile

Разрабатываю [сайт для "продвинутых" мобильных устройств](http://i.puush.ru).

Решил сделать плавный переход со страницы на страницу: все сдвигается налево, и в итоге новая страница заполняет весь экран, а старая "выпихивается". Метод вполне очевиден. Вот код:

```
$('#infafooter').live('touchend',function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-x','hidden');
    $('#body').css('display','table').animate({'left':'0'},400);
    $('#instr').animate({'left':'-100%'},400);
    setTimeout("$('#instr').css('display','none');$('body').css('overflow-x','auto');$('#body').css('position','relative')",400);
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.cookie('frst') == 120) {  //это проверка пока никакого смысла не несет...
        $('#instr').css({'display':'table','z-index':'10'});
        $('#body').css({
            'display':'none',
            'position':'absolute',
            'left':'100%',
            'top':'0'
        });
    }
});
```

Только вот проблема: при нажатии на далее перекидывает на новую страницу, и хотя палец от экрана уже отпустил нажимается ссылка. Можете сами попробовать (может быть потребуется попробовать несколько раз, чтобы "повезло" с фотографией).

Я тестирую на *iphone* в *safari*.

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Заранее благодарю.

**[UPD]**
Временно решил проблему тем, что поставил лоадинг, а после переход.

Comment: Пальцем в небо, но попробуйте event.preventDefault() или event.stopPropagation(), может поможет, только event в функцию передайте.

Comment: И ещё правильнее

    setTimeout(function(){  
        $('#instr').css('display','none');  
        $('body').css('overflow-x','auto');  
        $('#body').css('position','relative');  
    }, 400)